# Deshabilitar puertos USB desde CMD o Powershell

Tags: java, windows, cmd, powershell

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que, desde Java, ejecuto comandos de la CMD o de Powershell para llevar a cabo ciertas tareas (como, en este caso, deshabilitar los puertos USB  de un ordenador).

He estado buscando información y lo que verdaderamente se ajusta a lo que quiero realizar es habilitar la directiva de grupo local:

> "Directiva de Equipo Local --> Configuración del equipo --> Plantillas administrativas --> Sistema --> Acceso de almacenamiento extraíble --> Todas las clases de almacenamiento extraíble: denegar acceso a todo".

Cuando habilito esta política, automáticamente vuelve a redectar los USB's introducidos aplicando los cambios.

Inspeccioné los cambios en el registro que se realizan al activar dicha directiva y son, más o menos, los aquí explicados:

```
https://thorv.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/habilitardeshabilitar-escritura-y-lectura-de-dispositivos-de-almacenamiento-extraibles/
```

Dichos cambios en el registro puedo realizarlos fácilmente desde línea de comandos, pero el problema es que para que mi PC tome los valores actualizados de `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` tengo que reiniciar el equipo (Situación no deseable).

Lo que me lleva a las cuestiones:

- ¿Existe alguna forma de cambiar los valores del registro y que el PC tome dichos valores actualizados sin necesidad de reiniciar el equipo?.
- ¿Puedo cambiar las directivas de grupo local desde línea de comandos?.
- ¿Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras varias pruebas creo que esta es la solución óptima a mi problema:

1º-Deshabilitamos en el PC la funcionalidad para detectar dispositivos de almacenamiento externo nuevos, es decir, cuyos drivers no estén instalados en nuestro ordenador:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

2º-Eliminamos en el PC todos los drivers de los dispositivos USB instalados (Esto eliminará también la posibilidad de utilizar teclado y ratón, pero solo momentáneamente:

```
devcon.exe remove *USB*
```

3º- Volvemos a escanear los dispositivos USB conectados, de forma que Windows instalará automáticamente los drivers de los dispositivos que no sean de almacenamiento externo (Ej: Ratón, teclado...), obteniendo así el resultado deseado:

```
devcon.exe rescan
```

4º- Si queremos volver a permitir el uso de los USB de almacenamiento externo en nuestro ordenador, introduciremos el comando (Puede ser necesario quitar y volver a conectar el USB que queremos utilizar; en caso de que esté conectado al PC en el momento de introducir el comando):

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "3" /f
```

PD: Todo habrá de ejecutarse con privilegios de administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este comando que te permite modificar la clave de registro para desactivar el uso de los dispositivos USB.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

Para activarlo usa el valor `3`.

O Puedes bloquear el acceso a `Usbstor.pnf` y `Usbstor.inf`

```
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /d usuario
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /d user
```

Donde `usuario` es el usuario a quien deseas desactivar el acceso a los USB.
Para activarlo

```
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /p user:R
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /p user:R
```

Ambos comandos requieren de **Privilegios de Administrador**.

Respuesta Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13267533/2900932

Comment: Si te sirvió no estaría de mas que le dieras a la respuesta original algún Upvote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13267533/2900932

Comment: Gracias por responder. Ya había visto esa respuesta y ,supuestamente, también hay que desactivar el acceso para el usuario SYSTEM. Además no funcionó como esperaba pues tras seguir los pasos seguía detectando  dispositivos USB.

Comment: Además, en esa respuesta, no especifican que la modificación en el registro solo impide el uso de dispositivos USB que no se hayan conectado previamente al ordenador (cuyos drivers no estén instalados en el PC). La segunda opción sirve para suplir las carencias de la primera, ya que cambiando los permisos de esos archivos conseguimos que tampoco se permita la utilización de los dispositivos USB cuyos drivers si están instalados en el PC.